# How do I print and have user input in a text box in tkinter, Python 3.2.5?

Tags: python, input, textbox, tkinter

I am completely new to Python, and I just wrote a short bit of code that prints and asks for input in the python shell. It works like a diary where it asks for a date and then prints the entries for that date. I was hoping to incorporate this call and response into a text box in a tkinter GUI. I am wondering how to get this bit of code to perform in the text box instead of in the python shell.

```
month = int(float(input("Month(MM): ")))
day = int(float(input("Day(DD): ")))
year = int(float(input("Year(YYYY): ")))

print(str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/"+str(year))

noEntry = True

if month == 1 and day == 2 and year == 3456:
    noEntry = False
    print("Text")
if month == 7 and day == 8 and year == 9012:
    noEntry = False
    print("More Text")
if noEntry:
    print("No Entry Found")
```

I would also like to avoid calling for this code as an outside file. I want to know how to implement this code into a tkinter GUI text box, not how to retrieve a file which contains this code. Mostly because it is such a short program and it seems unnecessary. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Here is a basic Tk window that will take input for month, day and year

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()


label1 = Label( root, text="Month(MM)")
E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)

label2 = Label( root, text="Day(DD)")
E2 = Entry(root, bd =5)

label3 = Label( root, text="Year(YYYY)")
E3 = Entry(root, bd =5)

def getDate():
    print E1.get()
    print E2.get()
    print E3.get()

submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = getDate)

label1.pack()
E1.pack()
label2.pack()
E2.pack()
label3.pack()
E3.pack()
submit.pack(side =BOTTOM) 
root.mainloop()
```

when you click submit it prints the month day and year and im sure you can figure it out 
from there

**EDIT**

here is an example of a text box to display the diary entry:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, diary)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

in this example `diary` is the diary entry string!

Good Luck :)

Comment: It took a little work, but I got it up and running today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Serial Super! But how would you close the widget when the button is clicked?

Comment: Not enough rep to comment; but to have the box close you would add root.destroy() Under the getDate() function