# how to update a variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to tkinter. I want to write two numbers in two different entries in GUI and see their updated subtraction result on the display. here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *  
window = Tk()  

lb1 = Label(window,text="variable 1") 
lb1.pack()

name1=IntVar()  
en1=Entry(window, textvariable=name1)  
en1.pack()

lb2 = Label(window,text="variable 2")  
lb2.pack()

name2=IntVar()  
en2=Entry(window, textvariable=name2)  
en2.pack()

subt=IntVar()  
subt=name1.get()-name2.get()  
label_subt=Label(window, text=subt).pack()
```

how can I update `label_subt`?

Comment: Have you read any documentation? There is documentation for updating labels, and also for updating variables associated with labels.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question should explain what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17457178/8201979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the `subt` variable to the result of the subtraction before actually setting it to the label. Don't do that! Also, you set it as the `text`, not as the `textvariable`.

```
subt = IntVar()
Label(window, textvariable=subt).pack()
```

(Note that the result of `pack()` is not the `Label`, but `None`, so either move it to a separate line, as you did before, or just don't bind it to a variable that you never need anyway.)

Next, you can define a callback function for updating the value of the `subt` variable using the `set` method and `bind` that callback to any key press. You might want to narrow this down a bit, though.

```
def update(event):
    subt.set(name1.get() - name2.get())
window.bind_all("<Key>", update)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the config method on the label after every subtraction. You’ll have to use the entry.get() method to get the string of each entry. And don’t forget to use int() to convert it to an integer so you can do your subtraction otherwise you’ll get an error

label_subt.config(text=result)